# How to App running in background in ionic/android

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio, ionic-framework

I have build a hybrid (Android/iOS) app. I have to download a large number of files and do some processing with them in the background.

I built the app using Ionic. It works perfectly when it's in the foreground. I want to make the app run in the background and also do all of the processing in the background itself. I have tried Ionic's "native api cordova-plugin-background-mode" and it doesn't work for all versions of Android, especially Android 11.

It is only supported up to Android 8, but I have made some changes to the plugin files and have got it to work for Android 9/10. Also, the plugin is not guaranteed to be accepted by Android/iOS.

Please suggest some methods for both **Android** and **iOS**

Also, is it possible to incorporate packages available in android-studio / Xcode to applications built with Ionic?

Comment: Re iOS, a background `URLSession` allows you to download files in the background and then optionally launches your app in the background when it’s done. At that point, if your processing of the images takes a few seconds, you can do that when the background `URLSession` starts your app in the background. But if your “processing” may take more than 30 seconds, you have to use something like ([`BGProcessingTask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgprocessingtask/), in which the OS will launch your app at a time of the choosing of the OS.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the info, but is it possible to combine a feature that doesnt belong to ionic to an ionic app via Xcode

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m not an Ionic user, so I can’t say. I was just trying to share the fundamental iOS mechanisms, which ultimately constrain what an app can do on iOS platform. How you use these from Ionic is a separate question, which I can’t answer (which why I only posted a comment, rather than an answer). My apologies and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this plugin : **cordova-plugin-background**

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

         cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {

                //Exec Your Action here when the device in backgroundMode
         }
 }, false);
```

Comment: I assume the plugin you are suggesting is cordova-plugin-background-mode. In that case I have already tried the plugin, and the app stops after 15-20 mins on different mobile configurations